# How to make multiple if-conditions efficiently in Go?

Tags: go, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have to check a set of variables, if they contain an empty string as value. If the string is empty, it should be set to a default value of "no value". What is a efficient way to handle this in Golang?

Example given:

```
func defaultValue (myObject) {
    if myObject.name == "" {
        myObject.name = "no value"
    }
    if myObject.color == "" {
        myObject.color = "no value"
    }
    if myObject.typing == "" {
        myObject.typing = "no value"
    }
    if myObject.price == "" {
        myObject.price = "no value"
    }
}
```

I know how to do it with simple if statements, but I am wondering if there is an approach more efficient to this.

Comment: Don't confuse efficiency of the code with number of keystrokes or readability. You can't get more efficient than what you have. (also you have a value argument, so this function actually does nothing and the compiler may skip it entirely, making extra "efficient")

Answer (score 3):

You can create a separate function for that

```golang
func optional(input string) string {
   if input == "" {
       return "no value"
   }
   return input
}

func defaultValue (myObject) {
    myObject.name = optional(myObject.name)
    myObject.color = optional(myObject.color)
    myObject.typing = optional(myObject.typing)
    myObject.price = optional(myObject.price)
}
```

Comment: You can shorten it even more by making `optional` take a pointer as its argument.

Comment: Unless `myObject` is a pointer, this will only change the local copy, and changes will be discarded when the function returns.

Answer (score 3):

```golang
func aorb[T comparable](a, b T) T {
    var z T
    if a != z {
        return a
    }
    return b
}
```

```golang
func defaultValue(o *myObject) {
    o.name = aorb(o.name, "no value")
    o.color = aorb(o.color, "no value")
    o.typing = aorb(o.typing, "no value")
    o.price = aorb(o.price, "no value")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a generic helper that checks a specific field. If you pass the address of the field, the helper can also set the default value. Using variadic argument you can even list multiple fields (if they should have the same default value):

```
func check[T comparable](def T, fields ...*T) {
    var zero T
    for _, field := range fields {
        if *field == zero {
            *field = def
        }
    }
}
```

Testing it:

```
type Obj struct {
    name, color, typing, price string
}

func main() {
    o := Obj{color: "red"}
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", o)
    check("no value", &o.name, &o.color, &o.typing, &o.price)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", o)
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/iecY_HTejrB)):

```
main.Obj{name:"", color:"red", typing:"", price:""}
main.Obj{name:"no value", color:"red", typing:"no value", price:"no value"}
```

Comment: Note though that this would be less efficient in terms of execution complexity. It's only more efficient in terms of keystrokes.